# Problem loading huge .OBJ in Gazebo

Tags: ros, gazebo, model

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm working on Ubuntu 14.04 with Gazebo 2.2.3 and I want to load the 3D models provided as .obj files by this dataset: http://buildingparser.stanford.edu/dataset.html

I followed this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aP4sDyrRzpU

after that, I can see the model I created in the list, but if I try to insert it in the scene the window becomes black and gazebo gets stuck. The .dae file is 107mb, so maybe it's too big. Please, can someone point me out a solution?

Thanks, Federico

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/262290/problem-loading-huge-.obj-in-gazebo/) by [schizzz8](https://answers.ros.org/users/3511/schizzz8/) on ROS Answers with karma: 183 on 2017-05-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This would be better asked over at `answers.gazebosim.org`, but I would suspect the mesh is indeed too large for Gazebo to load and render.

A few suggestions:

- split it into multiple smaller segments
- subsample it

Depending on what you actually want to do, subsampling might not be acceptable, but that is something only you would know.

PS: I would really recommend to use a newer Gazebo if possible. 2.2.3 is ancient, and all the newer releases are available from the Gazebo package repositories. See [gazebo/tutorials/Which combination of ROS/Gazebo versions to use](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_wrapper_versions).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-05-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1